# Poisson distribution related problem with $X \sim POI(\mu)$

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

So there is this problem

> (Truncated Poisson) Let $X \sim POI(\mu)$, and suppose  we cannot observe $X=0$ so the observed random variable, $Y$, has discrete pdf
>
> $\displaystyle {f(y; \mu)=
>     \begin{cases}
>       \frac{e^{-\mu} \mu^y}{y! (1-e^{-\mu})} & y = 1,2,... \\
>       0 & \text{otherwise}
>     \end{cases}}$
>
> We desire to estimate $P[X>0] = 1 - e^{-\mu}$.  Show that an unbiased (but unreasonable) estimate of $1 - e^{-\mu}$ is given by $u(Y)$ where $u(y) = 0$ if $y$ is odd, and $u(y) = 2$ if $y$ is even.  Hint: Consider the power series expansion of $\frac{(e^\mu + e^{-\mu})}{2}$

So we have never gone over this kind of problem before in class and none of the people I talked to know how to do this problem.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that $E[u(Y)]=1-e^{-\mu}$. They gave you the hint to find the power series of $\frac{e^{\mu}+e^{-\mu}}{2}$. That is the function $\cosh(\cdot)$ and its power series is (show this yourself!):
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{\mu}+e^{-\mu}}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\mu^{2k}}{(2k)!}
\end{align}
Its radius of convergence is the whole real line.

Let's show unbiasedness:
\begin{align}
E[u(Y)]&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2\frac{e^{-\mu} \mu^{2k}}{(2k)!(1-e^{-\mu})}\\
&=\frac{2e^{-\mu}}{1-e^{-\mu}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\
&=\frac{2e^{-\mu}}{1-e^{-\mu}}\left(\frac{e^{\mu}+e^{-\mu}}{2}-1\right)\\
&=\frac{e^{-\mu}}{1-e^{-\mu}}\left( e^{\mu}+e^{-\mu}-2\right)\\
&=\frac{1+e^{-2\mu}-2e^{-\mu}}{1-e^{-\mu}}\\
&=\frac{(1-e^{-\mu})^2}{1-e^{-\mu}}\\
&=1-e^{-\mu}
\end{align}
Done!

Comment: So the power series of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$  are $1 + \mu + \frac{\mu^2}{2!} + \frac{\mu^3}{3!} + ....$ and $1 - \mu + \frac{\mu^2}{2!} - \frac{\mu^3}{3!} \pm ....$.  Then $e^\mu + e^{-\mu} = 2 + \frac{\mu^2}{2!} + \frac{2 \mu^4}{4!} + ...$.  Finally $\frac{e^\mu + e^{-\mu}}{2} = 1 + \frac{\mu^2}{2!}+ \frac{\mu^4}{4!} + .... =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\mu^{2k}}{(2k)!}$?

Comment: @NTT yes ${} {} {} {} $